# Calculating type Haskell

Tags: haskell

How to calculate type of (.)(.) in Haskell? 
I know that it should be

```
(.)(.) :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> (a1 -> b) -> a1 -> c
```

But how to calculate it without computer?

Comment: W h a t   H a v e   Y o u   T r i e d ?

Comment: i know that (.) :: (b->c)->(a->b) -> (a->c).

Comment: I think that (.)(.) should be (d->c)->(b->c)->(a->b)->(a->d) but it is wrong

Comment: Alright, but how did you come by that conjecture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(.)    :: (b        -> c                     ) -> ((a -> b)        -> (a -> c))
   (.) :: ((e -> f) -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f)))
(.)(.) ::                                         ((a -> (e -> f)) -> (a -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))))
(.)(.) :: (a -> (e -> f)) -> (a -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f)))
(.)(.) :: (a -> e -> f) -> a -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))
(.)(.) :: (a -> e -> f) -> a -> (d -> e) -> (d -> f)
(.)(.) :: (a -> e -> f) -> a -> (d -> e) -> d -> f
```

Answer (score 5):

### by (manual) pattern-*matching* and rewriting *types-variables*

`(.)` has type `(b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> a -> c`) so the first argument should have type `b -> c`.
Now if we use it again we have to substitute `b` with `b' -> c'` and `c` with `(a' -> b') -> a' -> c')` (the second `(.)` should have type `(b' -> c') -> ((a' -> b') -> a' -> c')`) and we get

```
(a -> b' -> c') -> a -> (a' -> b') -> a' -> c'
```

which is (after renaming) the same as above.

Note that I used `a -> b -> c = a -> (b -> c)` here

### using *GHCi*

yeah I know - you want it by hand - but *GHCi* is such a valuable tool that you really should use it to confirm your manual labor.

Here from a terminal:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :t (.)(.)
(.)(.) :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> (a1 -> b) -> a1 -> c
Prelude>
```

as you can see the type is `(a -> b -> c) -> a -> (a1 -> b) -> a1 -> c`

btw: `:t` is short for `:type` and you can see all commands with `:help` from inside a GHCi session.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know how to figure this out using pen & paper.

Comment: Yes, i want solution without computer (as i wrote above).

Comment: Why you need to substitute c with (a' -> b') -> a' -> c') ?

Comment: becase this is the second argument of the function I put into `(.)` (the second `(.)`)

Comment: see: you can look at `(.)` of beeing a function, that waits for a function `b -> c` and then returns a function `((a -> b) -> a -> c)` now this *function*  is `(.)` again and I don't want to mess up the types and so added ticks (`'`) to differentiate

Comment: isn't it wrong? For fun b->c you use type (b' ->c')->( (a'->b')->(a'->c')). Why it is correct? I don't understand it :/

Comment: because I apply `(.) :: (b -> c) -> ((a->b) -> a -> c))`  to `(.) :: (b' -> c') -> ((a'->b') -> a' -> c')` - so this **is** the `b -> c` and now I have to substitute the parts for `b` and `c` in `((a -> b) -> a -> c)` accordingly

Comment: it's really just *find/replace* with type-variables - you can do it in your editor if you like ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since I wasn't particularly satisfied with the missing explanations in the accepted answer, I give my POV as well:

```
-- this is the original type signature
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c

-- now because of haskell polymorphism,
-- even 'b' and 'c' and so on could be functions
--
-- (.)(.) means we shove the second function composition
-- into the first as an argument.
-- Let's give the second function a distinct type signature, so we
-- don't mix up the types:
(.) :: (e -> f) -> (d -> e) -> d -> f

-- Since the first argument of the initial (.) is of type (b -> c)
-- we could say the following if we apply the second (.) to it:
(b -> c) == (e -> f) -> (d -> e) -> d -> f

-- further, because of how currying works, as in
(e -> f) -> (d -> e) -> d -> f == (e -> f) -> ((d -> e) -> d -> f)
-- we can conclude
b == (e -> f)
c == (d -> e) -> d -> f

-- since we passed one argument in, the function arity changes,
-- so we'd actually only have (a -> b) -> a -> c left, but that
-- doesn't represent the types we have now, so we have to substitute
-- for b and c, so
(a -> b) -> a -> c
-- becomes
(.)(.) :: (a -> (e -> f)) -> a -> (d -> e) -> d -> f
-- and again because of currying we can also write
(.)(.) :: (a -> e -> f) -> a -> (d -> e) -> d -> f
```